# Protecting my HTTP BASIC-AUTH credentials on my Android app

Tags: android, rest

In a scenario where my Android application is powered by a remote database via my REST API, there is a safe way to store my HTTP BASIC AUTH credentials on my Android app? Safe from things like reverse engineering, root device?

Although I am new to android development, know to leave the credentials directly into the code of my application or sharedPreference is not at all safe. Please, any help is welcome =)

Comment: You can't protect plain text from a rooted device, so your only option would be to encrypt

Comment: there is no safe way to store the credentials in Android? Perhaps using the Android AccountManager class? I'm really lost ...

Comment: I was under the impression that AccountManager does encrypt credentials

Comment: Look [link] https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Comment: See if this answers your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23698241/2308683

Comment: Does your server have an authentication token mechanism? I don't think basic auth does. That's the only way to use an AccountManager

Comment: Look, what do you think? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453567/android-store-http-basic-password-username